# No ha sido posible ejecutar la orden

Tags: texmaker

No ha sido posible ejecutar la orden. (The following instruction cannot be executed.)

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Estoy realizando este documento en Texmaker y me genera este error.
este es la estructura es solo una prueba. (I am writing this document in Texmaker and it generates this error. This is the structure, it's just a test.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Andres Felipe Rincon}
\begin{document}
Hola mundo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This site operates exclusively in English.  But if the command `pdflatex` cannot be executed, that suggests something is wrong with your installation of TeX or TeXMaker, not your document.

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, you're using TeXmaker to write the document but not to compile it. Instead, you're looking to compile the document via a command line instruction. Is this right?

Comment: Save the test as `foo.tex` and check if you can run `pdflatex foo.tex` form the system prompt (be sure to execute this command in the working directory). If you cannot, then  pdflatex is not is a searchable path, or maybe you have installed texmaker, but no  LaTeX?